# Why isn't $destroy triggered when I call element.remove?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I can't figure out why the $destroy event is not triggered in the following example.  Can someone explain why it is not triggered, and in what scenarios it will be triggered?

Here's the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3Fz50aNeuculWKJ22iAX?p=preview

### JS

```
angular.module('testMod', [])
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.removeElem = function(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    angular.element(elem).remove();
  }
}).directive('testDir',[function() {
  return {
    scope:true,
    link: function(scope) {
      console.log('in directive');
      scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
        alert('destroyed');
      })
    }
  }
}]);
```

### HTML

```
<body ng-controller='testCtrl'>
  <div testDir id='test'>I will be removed.</div>
  <button ng-click='removeElem('test')'>remove</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is your listening for the `$destroy` event on the `scope`, but `$destroy` is being triggered on the `element`.

From angular.js source (I'm sure it's documentated on the website somewhere, but I didn't look):

> `$destroy` - AngularJS intercepts all jqLite/jQuery's DOM destruction
>   apis and fires this event on all DOM nodes being removed. This can
>   be used to clean up any 3rd party bindings to the DOM element before
>   it is removed.

Your directive should be (note that I added `scope`,`element`, and `attrs` as `link` arguments): Also, here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rZAoiesSgzVV1UGyIZbq?p=preview).

```
directive('testDir',[function() {
  return {
    scope:true,
    link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
      console.log('in directive');
      element.on('$destroy', function(){
        alert('destroyed');
      })
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: makes sense, should have realized that myself :)

Comment: As a follow up, should I manually destroy the scope of that directive in the element's $destroy event?  Will that be taken care of?

Comment: @TimMac How would you suggest I go about manually destroying the scope here?

Comment: @WebWanderer you can call the `$destroy()` method on the scope, which I've been doing on both the element `destroy` event and the scope `destroy` event.

Comment: @TimMac That's what I thought. Thanks for the reassurance.

Answer (score 2):

I am puzzled on why the $destroy event is not triggered on remove() method.

As per the docs, the $destroy event is triggered in two cases.

> 1. Just before a scope is destroyed
> 2. Just before an element is removed from the DOM

The purpose being "cleanup". You can listen on the $destroy event and perform necessary cleanups before letting a scope or element be destroyed. ngIf, ngSwitch, ngRepeat and other in-built directives/methods use the $destroy event to perform cleanups.

A best example would be the ngRepeat directive

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js

On line 339 you can notice the $destroy event being triggered. You can listen on the event and perform any action just before an item is removed from the list used by ngRepeat.

ngRepeat $destroy Example Plunk -- http://goo.gl/mkozCY

Comment: doing this destroys the controller's `$scope` and not the isolated scope of the element being removed.