# Child directive not receiving $destroy event when parent is destroyed

Tags: angularjs, destroy

I have an attribute directive attached to an element in one of my app's templates. When I route away from this template, the controller associated with it receives a destroy event. However, it appears that the directive does not also receive this event. Is there any way that I can receive it within the directive?

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
   <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.$on('destroy', function(){
  console.log('This fires just fine');
})
```

In the directive's link function:

```
scope.$on('destroy', function(){
  console.log('This will not fire');
})

element.on('destroy', function(){
  console.log('This will not fire either');
})
```

I found an issue from a few years ago that closely resembles my issue, but it was marked as resolved: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/683.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue at one point and ended up broadcasting down a custom destroy event that I listened for in the child scope.  Not sure how many "rules" it broke, but it fixed my issue of leaving behind children.

Comment: Ah, that works. Seems like there ought to be a better way to handle this though.

Comment: I agree, it feels very "hacky".  I struggled with this a considerable amount (particularly when needing to "destroy" from jQuery in a mixed app) and couldn't find a better way.  Would love to hear other community input :)  This was the best I could come up with after quite a bit of research and failed effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs: why isn't $destroy triggered when I call element.remove?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666514/angularjs-why-isnt-destroy-triggered-when-i-call-element-remove)

Comment: I don't think it's quite the same question, and the answer does not solve the problem -- `element.on('destroy')` does not get called in the directive either.

Comment: And.... I just realized that I'd been listening for 'destroy' and not '$destroy'. Sad that I only just caught that. Turns out that both `element.on('$destroy)` and `scope.$on('$destroy')` work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Both `element.on('$destroy)` and `scope.$on('$destroy')` will be called in a directive when the parent element is destroyed. The problem was listening for `'destroy'` instead of `'$destroy'`.

Comment: god damned, you just saved me !