# scope.$destroy is not triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a [plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LNQc2OlUBnXGrS4lKODR?p=preview) of the problem. The problem I'm facing here is fairly simple: calling $destroy manually or removing the element doesn't fire the $destroy event.

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {

  // call scope $destroy, However it doesn't fire the event
  scope.$destroy();

  // This also won't fire $destroy
  element.remove()


  scope.$on("$destroy", function handleDestroy() {
    console.log("I am destroyed")
  })
}
```

I am even more confused after reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666514/angularjs-why-isnt-destroy-triggered-when-i-call-element-remove#24669686). If `element` also gets a $destroy event, than why people unbind event at `scope` $destroy instead of `element` $destroy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callback for `$destroy` event is not set up yet in the code; so, move that to the line before you call the `scope.$destroy()`

So, it becomes:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {

  // this is fired when scope.$destroy() is called
  scope.$on("$destroy", function handleDestroy() {
    console.log("I am destroyed")
  });

  // 
  scope.$destroy();

  // this will fire when element.remove() is called
  element.on('$destroy', function(){
     console.log('elem destroyed'); 
  });

  // 
  element.remove();

}
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer, but `element.remove()` doesn't trigger $destroy

Comment: when you call `element.remove()`, `element.on('$destroy',...` is called, not `scope.$on('$destroy',...)` See my update above in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check thir [$destroy event](http://plnkr.co/edit/iRtTM3zBcjIvqMlG1h6h?p=preview)

```
app.directive("testDir", function() {
return function(scope) {
scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
  console.log("item removed");
});
```

};

And that : [angularjs-why-isnt-destroy-triggered-when-i-call-element-remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666514/angularjs-why-isnt-destroy-triggered-when-i-call-element-remove)